# VNC Server only listening for connections from localhost

Tags: vnc

I have installed **TightVNCServer** on Raspbian (the September 2.017 version) for my Raspberry Pi 2 B+ :

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$  vncserver -name Frambuesio -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 16

New 'Frambuesio' desktop at :1 on machine Frambuesio

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /home/luis/.vnc/Frambuesio:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/luis/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.

luis@Frambuesio:~$ netstat -ano | grep "5901"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

But my VNC Viewer (from RealVNC on a remote Windows machine) receives the message "**Connection refused**" when trying to connect, and the port doesn't seem to be listening:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ sudo nmap Frambuesio- -p 5900,5901,5902
[sudo] password for luis:

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-18 16:58 CEST
Nmap scan report for Frambuesio- (192.168.11.142)
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5900/tcp closed vnc
5901/tcp closed vnc-1
5902/tcp closed vnc-2
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:7D:7C:B0 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.67 seconds
```

If I try from **Ubuntu** 16.04.3 on another Raspberry Pi everything goes all right (note the different `netstat` results):

```
luis@Zarzaparrillo:~$ vncserver -name Zarzaparrillo -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 16

New 'Zarzaparrillo' desktop is Zarzaparrillo:1

Starting applications specified in /home/luis/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/luis/.vnc/Zarzaparrillo:1.log

luis@Zarzaparrillo:~$ netstat -ano | grep 5901
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Same results with **VNC4Server**.

I have read the [official Raspberry papers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/), consisting on installing the `realvnc-vnc-server` package. But the RealVNC program installs a ton of *extra packages* and is *not open source*, even when it is free for educative purposes. I would prefer some GNU's more open policies for my VNC, as long as it could be used in an enterprise production environment.

My **workaround** for now consists on using **X11vnc** to serve the display on another port:

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$  vncserver -name Frambuesio -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 16

[... on another terminal: ]
luis@Frambuesio:~$ sudo x11vnc -display :1 -passwd anypassword -auth guess -forever
```

... and now the X11vnc program makes display :1 available. Note that, as long as the port 5901 TCP is occupied, X11VNC uses the 5900 TCP (aka `:0 port`):

```
The VNC desktop is:      Frambuesio:0
PORT=5900
```

Note the `netstat` output, now in a **working** condition:

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ netstat -ano | grep 5900
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
luis@Frambuesio:~$ netstat -ano | grep 5901
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Why are my VNC servers failing and how could I solve this?

Comment: Note that x11vnc always serves on port 5900 as it is designed to share an existing X screen. The use of 5900 is nothing to do with the fact that 5901 is already in use.

Comment: Safer to keep it listening on local host and use a ssh tunnel

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem seems to be just a default argument on VNCServer with the improper (for your case) option.

From `vncserver` command line help:

```
[-localhost yes|no]    Only accept VNC connections from localhost
```

This should solve your problem:

```
vncserver -localhost no
```

Interpreting the same last example in the original question, note the `0.0.0.0:5900` meaning "listening connections **from anywhere** at 5900 TCP":

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ netstat -ano | grep 5900
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Meanwhile, note the `127.0.0.1:5901` meaning "listening connections **from localhost** at 5901 TCP"

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ netstat -ano | grep 5901
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Comment: Localhost is a sensible security default, given the extreme insecurity of the VNC protocol and increased attack surface of hanging the VNC daemon port out where attackers can directly get at it. Tunneling over SSH is the only way I recommend using VNC.

Comment: VPN tunneling could be another tunneling method, instead of (or in addition to) SSH.

Comment: localhost is certainly not a sensible default in the slightest. "Remote network access software" has "remote network access" disabled by default? As if someone installed the software with the intention of not actually using it... no this is an absurd default.

Comment: Fair point but nonetheless localhost-only is a "sensible security default" as @thrig put it: running VNC over the open internet is a no-go. The package/distribution could of course point this out when running or installing.

Comment: `vncserver -localhost no` gives me `Fatal server error:` ... `Unrecognized option: no`.

Comment: My private network inside my house isn't the "open internet". Nobody's saying the extra security shouldn't be easily available as an option, but making remote access software default to blocking remote access is insane. I just lost 4 hours on this. Not cool.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem and figured it out. From the command line run:

```
tigervncserver -localhost no :1
```

Make it permanent by adding into the file /etc/vnc.conf the option:

```
$localhost = "no"
```

Even though the file reads that the default is `localhost=no` that is not the case.

Comment: I am running a nodejs server on localhost :8080. Can I expose this to the internet using vnc?

Comment: I don't understand why the need for the `$`. It's never mentioned anywhere.